# Remove legend for plotly subplots: showlegend=False not working

Tags: python, plotly

I have created this figure with plotly and I want to remove the legend but the `showlegend=False` line isn't working. How can I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['person1', 'person2', 'person3'],
                   'feature':[18, 78, 35],
                   'year':[2029, 2028, 2027]
                  })

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2"),
                    )

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.id, y=df.feature,
                    marker=dict(color=[1, 2, 3], coloraxis="coloraxis")),
              1, 1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.year, y=df.feature,
                    marker=dict(color=[1, 2, 3], coloraxis="coloraxis")),
              1, 2)

# Update title and height
fig.update_layout(title_text="test", height=700)
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryorder':'total descending'},
                  autotypenumbers='convert types',
                 showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: You can stop specifying the color bar.　`#coloraxis="coloraxis"`

Comment: What do you mean by `line isn't working` do you mean the colorscale bar because there is no line in your graph?

Comment: If nothing else: `fig.update_coloraxes(showscale = False)`

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with subplots, the best approach is to set the showlegend inside the plot function:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.id, y=df.feature,
                marker=dict(color=[1, 2, 3], coloraxis="coloraxis", 
                            showlegend = False)), 1, 1)
```